# Keeping position of the wrapping blocks

Tags: html, css, layout

I have an upper block with a content wrapper, and a bottom block, which consists of two equal blocks also with content wrappers inside.

https://plnkr.co/edit/DTar7Wy5e37HnqbU2Gud?p=preview

```
<div class="upper">
  <div class="wrap"></div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-wrap"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-wrap"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Wrapper blocks have a dotted border.

No matter how big or small screen is, the smaller bottom wrap blocks together will be always the same size and position as upper bigger one, because smaller blocks have 150px max-width, which is half of the upper wrapper block max-width.

But when you change the width of the bottom composing blocks from 50% to 40% and 60%, position of the smaller wrapper blocks is also changing.

https://plnkr.co/edit/FTmHxm2F3vD8LhF5DM0d?p=preview

You can change their max-width to some other numbers (99 and 201 in my example), but it seems impossible to make them always keep the same position as the upper wrap.

So, is there any way to make these wrappers from the second example act like in the first example with 50%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap also the content in your bottom block:

```
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="wrap wrap-down">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="left-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="right-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

adding in your css the new `.wrap-down` class that I have created:

```
.wrap-down{
  display:flex;
}
```

and removing the `dotted black` border of `.left-content` and `.right-content`.

The problem that you had it is that you were wraping in your `upper div` the block, so you were taking the 90% of the width of the `.upper` class (its nearest parent).

In the block that you have down you were taking the 40% and 60% of your `.bottom` class, that were the 100% of the width of the page and not the 90% (by the wrapper) as in the first case.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Error404Stack/39L5q2js/) you have the `JSFiddle` in which you can see the effect.

Let me know if you have doubts about this.

**EDIT:** [This](https://jsfiddle.net/Error404Stack/39L5q2js/2/) `JSFiddle` works if you set the left and the right of the block to 50% with another solution than yours. I am trying to get it for another percentages. I will edit if new changes works.

**EDIT 2:** Finally I got the solution for your problem. See the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Error404Stack/39L5q2js/3/). It does not matter the % that you put to `.left` or `.right` class, it will make the effect that you want to achieve.

Comment: Well, the point is that I need to keep these background colors (lavender and beige), so I wanted to know, if it is possible to have the same border point for smaller wrappers and their colored parents blocks, and at the same time keep these wrappers together at the same position as the upper bigger one. It looks like an impossible task.

Comment: @qtxt Sorry, I did not notice that I change the background. Let me take a look and see if I can do something.

Comment: @qtxt I guess that the behaviour that you expect it is the same as in my second `JSFiddle` but with another percentages different to 50%, right? I am going to still look around the problem to see if I get a solution.

Comment: @qtxt Look my second edit. Now it works with the backgrounds that you wanted. I expect this would be the solution that you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I hope this will help in my real project.